# Which context do i need?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a dialog box and using the (this) isnt working. Up until now its just been a button calling a dialogbox but now the button within the called dialogbox needs to call another dialog. The Dialog dialogdelcon is the one with problem.

Here is the code:

```
case R.id.delappt:
        //rmvall();

        final Dialog dialogdelsel = new Dialog(this);
           dialogdelsel.setContentView(R.layout.delsel);
           dialogdelsel.setTitle("What would you like to do?");
           dialogdelsel.setCancelable(true);

          Button btndelsel = (Button) dialogdelsel.findViewById(R.id.btndelsel);
          btndelsel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   // delete selected code here.

               }
           });

         Button btndelall = (Button) dialogdelsel.findViewById(R.id.btndelall);
          btndelall.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   // delete all code here.
                  final Dialog dialogdelcon = new Dialog();
                   dialogdelcon.setContentView(R.layout.delcon);
                   dialogdelcon.setTitle("Deletion Confirmation");
                   dialogdelcon.setCancelable(true);

                  Button buttoncnclok = (Button) dialogdelcon.findViewById(R.id.btndelcon);
                   buttoncnclok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    // on click for cancel button
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View v) {
                           dialogdelcon.dismiss();
                       }
                   });

                 dialogdelcon.show();
               }
           });


        dialogdelsel.show();
        break;
```

Comment: Where does it fail? I'm guessing you need the activity context, myActivityName.this

Comment: What exactly would my activity name be? I'm still new to android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getApplicationContext()` or use `YourActictyName.this` Because `this` refers the button `click listner` ,not your class `Object`

Answer (score 0):

If this code is in the `onCreate()` method, or similiar, add `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this` and you should be fine. That's because `this` in a Button-context will refer to the button environment.

Answer (score 0):

To improve the isolation between the two dialogs, it would be best to call showDialog(R.id.delapptcon) from the onClick handler. Then load the new dialog in the onCreateDialog of your activity. In this way, you can create more reusable dialogs and avoid the scoping issue you have now.