# which context do I need?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-context

I've the class:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
public class xxx{

public void updateObjects(){

deleteIntents(Context context, int x);
(...)
for(...){
    //Update each object ofdb4o with the new object value's.
    (...)
    doIntents(context,mil,obj);
    }
            (...)
    }

public void doIntents(Context context, long mil, ClassObjects obj){
(...)
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, obj.getId(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
(...)
}
}

public void deleteIntents(Context context, int x){
            intent = new Intent(context, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
            for(int i=1;i<x;i++){
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, i, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
            }
            Log.d(TAG,"intents removed");
        }
```

And work's Ok.. But I need use `deleteIntents(Context context, int x)` from main Activity.. With a button:

```
xxx.deleteIntents(getApplicationContext(),x);
```

But doesn't work.. I think that I've a problem with the context but I don't know why..

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: "doesn't work" - that is not helpful at all. Please elaborate on that.

Comment: @Paul I don't have any exception :( Do you know the context that I need for call the method in the Main Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry,

I had forgotten to instantiate the AlarmManager before:

```
public void deleteIntents(Context context, int x){
            alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService (Service.ALARM_SERVICE);
            intent = new Intent(context, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
            for(int i=1;i<x;i++){
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, i, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
            }
            Log.d(TAG,"intents removed");
        }
```

Now Work's!! Thank you both!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Each `Activity` is a `Context` object.

So inside `Activity` class just use "this" pointer instead of `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: Behzadian I've used getApplicationContext() because i've read the solution in the thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776631/which-context-do-i-need (inside button)